# ReactJS capturing forward button press in component

Tags: reactjs

How would one catch if the forward button is pressed in a component?  I assumed that the forward button would fire the `componentDidMount` method, but I am finding that to be incorrect?  I need to dynamically load data everytime the component is displayed.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-hill-ffoq9

Thank you

Comment: what is `the forward button`?

Comment: The browser forward button

Comment: Why do you want to do that? you may not have the right approach. you're using react router?

Comment: Your approach is unclear, what exactly do you want to achieve? The browser API limitations will not allow you to detect the changes, but react-router might. But that's not efficient.

Comment: I am and if it were up to me I would somehow disable the forward and back buttons; however, I have a multi-purpose component that will load data based on the pathname.  Clicking the link fires the proper methods to load the data.  If I hit the back button, then the forward button, the component does not know how to repsond; therefore nothing is displayed.

Comment: you should remove `exact` from `<Route exact path="/Login" component={Login} />` => `<Route path="/Login" component={Login} />` otherwise the route will not match `/Login/Terms`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And it does.

I modified your routing based on react-router docs and now it works.

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-resonance-2guwg